# 17 characthers Facebook user id gets stored with a different value in MYSQL using Facebook php SDK v2.10

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
    $user = $response->getGraphUser();
    $fid = $user['id'];

    echo($fid); //10155784607879101

    //in mysql table i get 2147483647 in the fid column for the following query

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO users(fid) VALUES (:fid)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':fid', $fid);
    $stmt->execute();

    //in this case $fid not equals $stmt->bindParam(':fid', $fid);
```

---

I read this in the Facebook developers documentation:

id
numeric string
The id of this person's user account. This ID is unique to each app and cannot be used across different apps. Our upgrade guide provides more information about app-specific IDs
Core

---

I cannot identify my users when they return on my site and login using Facebook.
Anyone has suggestion?

Thanks in advance,

Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store the Facebook ID as a number you need the field to be an unsigned BIGINT.

However, now Facebook lists the data type of the ID as [string](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user), so you should store it with an alphanumeric type to avoid breaking your app in the future (thanks to CBroe for pointing it out).

Comment: I did it its recorded but not shown as my reputation is under 15. Thank you again.

Comment: That's for votes. To accept click the grey check under the score.

Comment: Bad answer. Facebook has hinted that the format might change some day, and that applications should be prepared to handle alpha-numeric ids. Store them as text. They where never “numbers” to begin with, so storing them as integers is nonsense.

Comment: @CBroe hadn’t seen that. Have some upgrading to do :). I updated the answer, thank you.